# Get Image of Email with PHP

Tags: php, imap

I'm trying to get an image from an E-mail which is sent to my mailserver and save the file to the server. I tried it with this code:

```
                $no_of_occurences = 0;
                $intStatic = 2;

                $decode = imap_fetchbody($mbox, $val , null);    
                $no_of_occurences = substr_count($decode,"Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64");
                $no_of_occurences--;
                echo $no_of_occurences;   
                if($no_of_occurences > 0){
                    for($i = 0; $i < $no_of_occurences; $i++){  
                        $strChange =   strval($intStatic+$i);
                        $decode = imap_fetchbody($mbox, $val , $strChange);
                        $data = base64_decode($decode);
                        $x = 1;
                        $fName = './images/'.$ticketurl."_".$x. '.png';
                        while(file_exists($fName)){
                            $x++;
                            $fName = './images/'.$ticketurl."_".$x. '.png';
                        }
                        if($x==500){
                            $valid = false;
                            exit;
                        }

                        $file = $fName;
                        $success = file_put_contents($file, $data);        
                    }           
                }
```

This code is working fine but only if you have one type of appendage in it. If you place one image inline the mail it is working. If you place one as an attachment, it also works. But if you got both (inline and as attachment) it's just getting one image and a second clean png file.
Any suggestions how to solve this behavior?

Comment: Body part numbers do not always just increase, 1, 2, 3.  It's set up as a tree, they can be 1.1, 1.2, 2, 2.1.  If you have inline and attachment images, the format is likely to be more difficult.  Can you download the whole message and use a MIME parser to extract the parts you want?

Comment: Wow that's a very good point. I will try this idea. Thanks for your help!